# How to tell the browser to cache a specific element in HTML document

Tags: html, caching, browser

I generate output with php. I've been reading about caching HTML elements (e.g. images, text) in the browser so that these don't have to be reloaded.

However, I haven't found the right directions on how to get it done. It's like "simply cache the elements you want and you're done!" - great, but how do I cache something like this:

```
<div id="ubiquitous_heading">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" />
    <span>Welcome to this dummy website</span>
</div>
```

Is there a header that can target HTML elements and designate what to cache and what not?
I'm referring to something structured like:

```
#ubiquitous_heading {
   cache: yes;
}
#no_cache_please {
   cache: no;
}
```

Is there a way to do that? What exactly do people mean when they say "`you can cache a specific element in your HTML?`" referring to **every** element (including links to css, js).

Thank you for clearing this up for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only cache responses to HTTP requests, not parts of them. In theory, you could place a shared header in a frame and have it cached, but most often it'll be messier and not really worth the trouble. What you can and *should* cache is images, scripts and stylesheets; generally, all external resources which are static and fetched in a separate request.

Comment: I understand, but could you please elaborate on how to cache those images, js, css files? is it something like <img cache="cache" />?

Comment: You would need to do that on the server side. In Apache, you can use `mod_expires` or similar via the server configuration or `.htaccess`, or you could do write out the headers dynamically in a programming langues (e.g. `header()` in PHP).

Answer (score 2):

Only resources can be cached. Your standard web request has the following resources:

- html page(s)
- script files
- stylesheets
- images
- fonts (hopefully coming soon!)

Any and all of these can be cached, however, you cannot cache part of one resource at the browser level (e.g. one rule in a stylesheet, or one element in an html page).